# Method not found: 'Int32 Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SemanticAst.QueryNode.get_Kind()'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm creating a WebApi application using MVC 4 which needs to support oData.

I installed the package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData (Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -Pre) as recommended but when filtering [for example: /api/cars?$filter=startswith(Name,'F')] I'm getting the exception:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Method not found: 'Int32 Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SemanticAst.QueryNode.get_Kind()'.","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.ValidateSingleValueNode(SingleValueNode node, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.ValidateQueryNode(QueryNode node, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ExecuteQuery(IEnumerable query, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a binary incompatibility with a version of the underlying OData library that caused this issue. I'd strongly recommend using our nightly builds. Just use this command instead in your package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -Source http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/ -Pre
```

This will also get you a version of Web API OData support that's much closer to the final release bits.